# How to merge object in MongoDb Aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with mongoDB aggregation. I want to ask how to merge object in MongoDb Aggregation. My mongodb query is like:

```
db.userDetail.aggregate([
    {$match: {jurusan: data[0].jurusan}},
  { $limit: 5 },
  { $lookup: { from: "userdetails", localField: "user", foreignField: "user", as: "userdetail"}},
  { $lookup: { from: "majors", localField: "userdetail.jurusan", foreignField: "_id", as: "jurusan"}},
  { $lookup: { from: "verifyusers", let:{ userdetail: "$userdetail" }, pipeline: [{ $match: { status: "Selesai", $expr: {$in: ["$user", "$$userdetail.user"]}}}], as: "verify"}},
  { $unwind: {
    path: "$userdetail",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
  }},
  { $unwind: {
    path: "$jurusan",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
  }},
  
  { $skip: parseInt(skip) ? parseInt(skip) : 0 },
  { $project:{
      "_id": 0, 
      "userdetail.jurusan": 1,
      "jurusan": 1,
      "verify._id": 1,
      "verify.status": "Selesai",
    }
  },
  ], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    res.send(result);
  });
```

Result query:

```
{
    "jurusan": {
        "_id": "5fa89bb4bb94930eb0940cc9",
        "nama": "Teknik Informatika",
        "createdAt": "2020-11-09T01:30:28.618Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-11-09T01:30:28.618Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "userdetail": {
        "jurusan": "5fa89bb4bb94930eb0940cc9"
    },
    "verify": []
},
```

But i want result query like this:

```
{
    
    "userdetail": {
        "jurusan": {
           "_id": "5fa89bb4bb94930eb0940cc9",
           "nama": "Teknik Informatika",
           "createdAt": "2020-11-09T01:30:28.618Z",
           "updatedAt": "2020-11-09T01:30:28.618Z",
           "__v": 0
       },
    },
    "verify": []
},
```

My question is, how to merge "jurusan" object outside with "jurusan" inside "userdetail" object? That "jurusan" lookup result should be inside "userdetail".

Thanks before.

Comment: @turivishal error: $mergeObjects requires object inputs, but input 5fa89bb4bb94930eb0940cc9 is of type objectId

Comment: you just need to do in your $project stage `{ "userdetail.jurusan": "$jurusan" }` look at the working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6OLhtCg57BF)

Comment: @turivishal ok thanks, it work now. I need to add one by one field in userdetail collection. Because i cant just only type "userdetail": 1, it will error.